# html5 video does not work with android webview

Tags: android, html, webview, uiwebview, html5-video

I have been running the android app in webview for a year.
But there are some customers who say html5 video is not playing in my app a few days ago.
I have five phones for testing, and there is nothing wrong with all my phones. Most customers are using the app without any problems.

I changed the preload property value from auto to meta because I want to be due to network load.

The picture below is a screenshot from the customer.
There is a time of 27:10, and there is no spinner for loading. (I think loading is over)
However, the customer can not press the play button, and when the play button is pressed, an orange line appears around the video element.

[image]

The customer's cell phone is galaxy note 8 & galaxy J7 and the android version is 8. But in my test there was no problem. And there are Android 8 customers who are using the service without any problems.

How can I solve it? thanks.

html

```
<video preload="meta" width="95%" autoplay="autoplay" controls="" playsinline="">               
        <source type="video/mp4" src="url.../file.mp4">
        HTML5 is not supported.
    </video>
```

android - MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    private BackPressCloseHandler backPressCloseHandler = new BackPressCloseHandler(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        /* webView settings */
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new FullscreenableChromeClient(MainActivity.this));
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientClass());

        webView.loadUrl("MY URL IS HERE");
    } //onCreate

    private class WebViewClientClass extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

custom class to enable video Fullscreen

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class FullscreenableChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    private Activity mActivity = null;

    private View mCustomView;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
    private int mOriginalOrientation;
    private FrameLayout mFullscreenContainer;
    private static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    public FullscreenableChromeClient(Activity activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            if (mCustomView != null) {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }

            mOriginalOrientation = mActivity.getRequestedOrientation();
            FrameLayout decor = (FrameLayout) mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();
            mFullscreenContainer = new FullscreenHolder(mActivity);
            mFullscreenContainer.addView(view, COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS);
            decor.addView(mFullscreenContainer, COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS);
            mCustomView = view;
            setFullscreen(true);
            mCustomViewCallback = callback;
//          mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(requestedOrientation);

        }

        super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, int requestedOrientation, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback) {
        this.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideCustomView() {
        if (mCustomView == null) {
            return;
        }

        setFullscreen(false);
        FrameLayout decor = (FrameLayout) mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        decor.removeView(mFullscreenContainer);
        mFullscreenContainer = null;
        mCustomView = null;
        mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
        mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(mOriginalOrientation);

    }

    private void setFullscreen(boolean enabled) {

        Window win = mActivity.getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
        final int bits = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        if (enabled) {
            winParams.flags |= bits;
        } else {
            winParams.flags &= ~bits;
            if (mCustomView != null) {
                mCustomView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        win.setAttributes(winParams);
    }

    private static class FullscreenHolder extends FrameLayout {
        public FullscreenHolder(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, android.R.color.black));
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

manifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="...">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="....webview.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name="....webview.IntroActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Same situation here, except I'm able to reproduce on my phone. An update to the Android System WebView was updated March 11 (not sure whether that's when the update was published or that's when my phone updated; just going off the "last updated" in the Google Play Store for Android System WebView), so I'm presuming that did it.

Comment: I've received reports from Samsung 8 and Huawei P20 users with the same issue

Comment: I succeeded in reproducing the same symptoms on my test cell phone. I waited almost five minutes and the orange line disappeared and I was able to play the video. Is it a network problem? But my server was fine and on other test phones using the same WiFi, loading was instantly complete. Thanks to the advice of the people who answered, I'm going to use JavaScript.

Comment: This is definitely a bug in the Android System WebView. I'm experiencing this issue on a Galaxy S8 with Android Pie using Android WebView version 73.0.3683.90. I rolled back to version 71.0.3578.99 and this problem goes away.

Comment: Videos in a WebView used to work for me, but not anymore (after Pie update?) on my S9+.  My phone says Android System WebView disabled (v69), with Chrome enabled.

Answer (score 7):

The below code is working fine for me please check once

**add this line in manifest file**

```
   <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webview = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webview.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    webview.loadUrl("https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp");
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: The line that fixed it for me is webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);  (API 17) But I still can't get the full-screen button to work anymore!

Comment: @ErnieThomason I had the same problem and setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false) fixed it !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Android System Webview 73 on my video app. It seems like there is some style issue with the default html5 video player. I can do the auto play or call the play() function in javascript.

My solution is to use some other javascript video player. I used videoJS to replace the video player interface and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Since javascript calls to play/pause the video work, I fixed this in our app by including a div in front of the video and sizing it to match the play button that Android places near the center of the video. Here is a snippet of the React:

```
const isAndroid = () => navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') >= 0;

let videoPlayer;

...

<div className="video-wrap">
  <video
    ref={node => videoPlayer = node}
    controls
    controlsList="nodownload"
    crossOrigin="anonymous"
    poster={episode.posterUrl}
  >
    <source src={episode.h264Url} type="video/mp4" />
    {episode.webmUrl ? (
      <source src={episode.webmUrl} type="video/webm" />
    ) : null}
    {episode.vttUrl ? (
      <track kind="captions" label="English" src={episode.vttUrl} srcLang="en" />
    ) : null}
  </video>

  { isAndroid() ? (
    <div
      className="android-playback-fix"
      onClick={e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (videoPlayer.paused) {
          videoPlayer.play();
        } else {
          videoPlayer.pause();
        }
      }}
    ></div>
  ) : null}
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.video-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.android-playback-fix {
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 75px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I experience same issues.

To fix that.

Put an `id` on your HTML video tag and call that `id` in your java code.

for example

```
<video id = "video" preload="meta" width="95%" autoplay="autoplay" controls="" playsinline=""><source type="video/mp4" src="url.../file.mp4"></video>
```

On `onPageFinished` - an override for `WebViewClient` ,  put this code

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementById('video').play(); })()");
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementById('video').pause(); })()");
```

This will inject javascript function to allow autoplay the video